# Soap Response without namespaces

Tags: java, spring, soap-client

I have received below response in Java Spring Boot ws application:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <dateTime>23082020033057</dateTime>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <TestResponse>
         <ResponseCode>06</ResponseCode>
      </TestResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm parsing response in SOAPHandler class.

```
public class HeaderHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    
    private static final String SOAP_ENV_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    private static final String PREFERRED_PREFIX = "soapenv";

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
            SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
    }
}
```

I received below error message.

```
**javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: HeaderElements must be namespace qualified**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding SOAP header elements without namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067832/adding-soap-header-elements-without-namespace)

Comment: No, I'm looking to parse SOAP response at any cost. It would great if you suggest any alternative.

Comment: But it, by definition, needs the namespace, as *All immediate child elements of the Header element must be namespace-qualified*.

Comment: I understand but I don't have any control on it. Please suggest how I can parse response.